# UserControl VisualStates do not appear in Blend

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, expression-blend, vsm

The States pane in Blend 4 does not appear to show the VisualStates declared on a UserControl using the TemplateVisualState attribute. Is this to be expected and if so why? Creating the States manually in Blend seems to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User controls aren't typically designed to be modified or re-templated the same way that regular controls are.

Most of the time where you want a control to be editable and offer alternative animations (through the states panel for instance) you're going to want to build something that derives from a proper custom control type.

Comment: I expected as much, thank you for clarifying. I've been experimenting with tying together the VSM and MVVM to try to get the most out of Blend, hence the UserControls.